# How to implement poll on a Future in a non-blocking manner in futures 0.3?

Tags: rust

**Update**: This question is not relevant anymore since `Context` [got removed](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/54339) from the `poll()` signature.

---

I'm trying to implement a simple [`Future`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/future/trait.Future.html) with the [futures crate](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/futures-rs) v0.3:  opening a `File`.

My future currently looks like this:

```
struct OpenFuture {
    options: OpenOptions,
    path:    PathBuf,
    output:  Option<io::Result<File>>,
}
```

To implement `Future`, I came up with this:

```
impl Future for OpenFuture {
    type Output = io::Result<File>;

    fn poll(mut self: PinMut<Self>, cx: &mut Context) -> Poll<Self::Output> {
        if let Some(file) = self.file.take() {
            Poll::Ready(file)
        } else {
            let waker = cx.waker().clone();
            cx.spawner().spawn_obj(
                Box::new(lazy(move |_| {
                    // self.file = Some(self.options.open(&self.path));
                    waker.wake();
                })).into(),
            );
            Poll::Pending
        }
    }
}
```

If the output is `Option::Some`, it can be taken and the future is ready, this is straightforward. But if it's not ready, I don't want to block the thread as mentioned in the Documentation:

> An implementation of `poll` should strive to return quickly, and must never block. Returning quickly prevents unnecessarily clogging up threads or event loops. If it is known ahead of time that a call to `poll` may end up taking awhile, the work should be offloaded to a thread pool (or something similar) to ensure that `poll` can return quickly.

So I want to offload the work. Since I have a [`Context`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/task/struct.Context.html) passed to the `poll` method, I have access to a [`Spawn`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/task/trait.Spawn.html) and a [`Waker`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/task/struct.Waker.html). The `Spawn` should take a task, that opens the file. After the file is open, it notifies with `waker.wake()`.

The provided code doesn't work when uncommenting the line due to a lifetime error:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime due to conflicting requirements
    |
    |                           Box::new(lazy(move |_| {
    |  _______________________________________^
    | |                             self.file = Some(self.options.open(&self.path));
    | |                             waker.wake();
    | |                         })).into(),
    | |_________________________^
    |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the method body...
    |
    |               fn poll(mut self: PinMut<Self>, cx: &mut Context) -> Poll<Self::Output> {
    |  _____________^
    | |                 if let Some(file) = self.file.take() {
    | |                     Poll::Ready(file)
    | |                 } else {
...   |
    | |                 }
    | |             }
    | |_____________^
    = note: ...so that the types are compatible:
            expected std::pin::PinMut<'_, _>
               found std::pin::PinMut<'_, _>
    = note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the static lifetime...
    = note: ...so that the expression is assignable:
            expected std::future::FutureObj<'static, _>
               found std::future::FutureObj<'_, _>
```

How this can be solved?

Additionally, [`Spawn::spawn_obj`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/task/trait.Spawn.html#tymethod.spawn_obj) returns a `Result`. How this result can be handled? Is it recommended to just return `io::ErrorKind::Other`?

Comment: If you wish to implement a future, the underlying primitives should be asynchronous (non-blocking). File I/O in Rust currently is blocking, presumably because it is difficult to implement cross-platform. So unfortunately, this approach will not work, regardless of your specific question regarding lifetimes.

Comment: This is why I want to queue the task at the spawner `cx.spawner().spawn_obj()`

Comment: Spawning refers to spawning a *future*; you can define a future in terms of one or more other futures (and even then spawning as you are attempting here is usually not needed). But you don't have a future to work with; you only have a blocking method call. That's it – there is no other option but to make (this part of) your program blocking since there is no alternative (async) implementation right now AFAIK. If you deal with many thousands of these blocking file operations you may consider thread pools instead.

Comment: Hmm, I see your point. I basically wrapping a `Future` in another `Future`...